# Convert CSV with a column that has a collection of coordinates into a spatial file

Tags: qgis

I have a CSV that has the Jsonata ( `$string($eval(Location).coordinates)` ) representation of the feature in a column. It is not stored in a .json file.

Can we import this into QGIS so that it has the attribution and spatial representation?

```
1   [Line]  [[145.44718131423,-17.2122806274458],[145.447615496814,-17.2116429871501],[145.448055714369,-17.2121269022115]] Test Line
2   [Polygon]       [[[145.443768203259,-17.2042553589467],[145.447121970356,-17.202962405607],[145.447320118546,-17.2054797649401],[145.443768203259,-17.2042553589467]]]  Test Polygon
```

I have tried to import using Delimited Text:WKT but get an error as this isn't valid WKT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CSV file contains GeoJSON coordinates. You need to preprocess the file to GeoJSON. I've created a sample, a Python script you can run within PyQGIS console or Python (no dependencies to QGIS in my code). It will output a GeoJSON file you can open as a vector file. I catch when Line, Polygon otherwise coordinates are considered as points

Here the CSV file input sample `in.csv` (tab separated)

```
identifier  typegeom    coordinatesjson title
1   [Line]  [[145.44718131423,-17.2122806274458],[145.447615496814,-17.2116429871501],[145.448055714369,-17.2121269022115]] Test Line
2   [Polygon]   [[[145.443768203259,-17.2042553589467],[145.447121970356,-17.202962405607],[145.447320118546,-17.2054797649401],[145.443768203259,-17.2042553589467]]]  Test Polygon
```

Here the code to process the file to GeoJSON

```py
import csv
import json

features = []
with open('in.csv') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inputfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        geom = {"coordinates": json.loads(row['coordinatesjson'])}
        if row['typegeom'] == '[Polygon]':
            geom["type"] =  "Polygon"
        elif row['typegeom'] == '[Line]':
            geom["type"] = "LineString"
        else:
            geom["type"] = "Point"
        row.pop('coordinatesjson')
        feature = {
           "type": "Feature",
           "properties": row,
           "geometry": geom
        }
        features.append(feature)

with open('out.geojson', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features}, outfile)
```

The output file `out.geojson` look like below

```json
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"identifier": "1", "typegeom": "[Line]", "title": "Test Line"}, "geometry": {"coordinates": [[145.44718131423, -17.2122806274458], [145.447615496814, -17.2116429871501], [145.448055714369, -17.2121269022115]], "type": "LineString"}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"identifier": "2", "typegeom": "[Polygon]", "title": "Test Polygon"}, "geometry": {"coordinates": [[[145.443768203259, -17.2042553589467], [145.447121970356, -17.202962405607], [145.447320118546, -17.2054797649401], [145.443768203259, -17.2042553589467]]], "type": "Polygon"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the column is not geometry in wkt format.
The right example string is: POLYGON ((coordinates)).

Depending on the size of the file, you can edit it manually, or use, for example, notepad ++ and [POLYGON] to convert to POLYGON and parentheses. [] on ().

If you have three brackets [[[that means MULTIPOLYGON.